# Remove spaces in front of any first character and after any last character

Tags: php, regex, string, trim

I would like to trim **all spaces** in front in any first character (except space, could be a number or an alphabetic character) and after any last character. Using `/([A-Z ])\w+/`, actually did good, but my `$output`doesn't. What do I have to do to get 'Any Word' in the end? And this should work for any number of words not only two inside the spaces.

```
$text = '                   Any Word                ';

preg_match_all('/([A-Z ])\w+/', $text, $output);

var_dump($output);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: does `trim` not do what you want?

Comment: I don't know why you doesn't see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44213778/6521116). Mine come first with demo and same with the accepted one.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [***trim***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function that remove any space from start and end of string:

```
$text = '                   Any Word                ';

$output = trim($text);

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Hahaaa, oh my good. Yes, very good solution. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

what about **[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)**, it should work for you. Check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/806138)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a regex here, you can try matching with the pattern `\s+(.*)\s+`:

```
$string = '                   Any Word                ';
preg_match('/\\s+(.*)\s+/', $string, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

**Output:**

```
Any Word
```

However, you could also use `trim()`.

## Demo

Comment: Thanks, yes. Have totally forgotten about `trim()`.